# Why /[^un]*successful$/ match "Mission: unsuccessful", but /[^un]+successful$/ does not?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I am learning Regex right now. If * means 0 or more matches and + means 1 or more matches, shouldn't both those regex phrases not match the string?

Answer (score 4):

`[^un]` means match any character other than `u` or `n`.  So `[^un]*succesful` matches because it repeats 0 times.  `[^un]+successful` would fail because there is an `n` character directly before successful.

Answer (score 2):

Because `[^un]` means "not u or n", and `*` means 0 or more (as you already know...)
In that case there are 0 occurrences of "not u or n" followed by "successful", so that matches. The `+` (1 or more) doesn't cause there aren't any such occurences.

Answer (score 0):

Because
"Mission: unsuccessful" does not start with "unsuccessful".

[^un]*successful only worked because it just match "successful" because [^un]* is is not useful for "Mission: unsuccessful" as the regex would generally just work with anything like "-successful" regardless of the validity of [^un]*.

[^un]+successful means that it is has to also start with un-.

So just remove ^ and it should match like this
[un]+successful$

Or (un)?successful$ which works better.